# Disabling relative line numbers in SpaceVim

Tags: vim

I find it annoying having to type

```
:set nrnu
```

everytime I open a file. If I make a .vimrc file then spacevim no longer loads, I just get vanilla vim.

Answer (score 3):

In your SpaceVim configuration file. Just add:

```
relativenumber=false
```